# bash echo command ignored in function loop

Tags: bash

I simplified my bash script to the scope of the problem. I was wondering how come when I do this...

```
#!/bin/bash                                
                                            
read -p "Please enter your name: " name    
                                            
function test()                            
{                                          
    while true                             
    do                                     
        echo $name                         
    done                                   
}                                          
                                            
echo $(test)
```

the `echo` command doesn't loop the name in the terminal. However, if I were to remove the function and have the `while` loop by itself like so....

```
#!/bin/bash                                
                                           
read -p "Please enter your name: " name    
                                                 
while true                             
do                                     
   echo $name                         
done
```

It would work. Or if I do this, it will also work

```
#!/bin/bash
                            
read -p "Please enter your name: " name    
        
function test()                            
{    
    echo $name                                                           
}                                          
                                            
echo $(test)
```

What's causing the `echo` command to not to not display the name. This only happens when the `echo` command is inside a `while` loop whilst being inside a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are bash variables not global if sourced script runs in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772668/why-are-bash-variables-not-global-if-sourced-script-runs-in-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's causing the echo command to not to not display the name

The parent shell is waiting for the subshell to exit before expanding the command subsitution to it's contents. Because the subshell never exits (as it's in an endless loop), the `echo` command never gets executed.

```
echo $(test)
     ^^    ^  - shell tries to expand command substitution
                so it runs a subshell with redirected output
                and waitpid()s on it.
       ^^^^   - subshell executes `test` and never exits
                cause its an endless loop.
                Parent shell will endlessly wait on subshell to exit.
```

Note that [test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) is already a very standard shell builtin for testing expressions. Defining such function which will cause to overwrite the builtin may cause unexpected problems.

For some reading I could recommend [bash guide functions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions).

Comment: I'm new to bash, so what would be the best way to call the function and have it execute in the way I expected. Also I only used `test` for the example. My function was named something else in my actual program haha

Comment: just type the name of the function... Doing `echo $(something)` is a useless use of `echo`, it's like `echo $(echo $(echo $(echo $(something))))`. Just `something`. On a side note, results from unquoted expansions undergo word splitting expansion - check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net and preferably quote the expansions  - research when to use double quotes in bash.

Comment: My apologies...I was reading someone elses script and saw that they were calling functions that way. So I thought that was the way you were suppose to call functions. Thank you for letting me know, I learned something new today